# Changing server behaviour periodically

Tags: php, file

I have a `common settings file` shared between `PHP` and my client's `javascript` to read from.
My server is using another (external) server [that is down quite often] for a `specific validation`.
The `common settings file` is specifying whether that `validation` should be carried out or not.

I would like my server to change the `common settings file` to not to check upon server down for about 30 minutes and then change the setting back again (the setting is "0"/"1").

I thought I should write a script that is run upon first occasion of server down.The script would go ahead and look something like that:

```
change_settings_file("DO_VALIDATION",0); 
sleep(30*60);
change_settings_file("DO_VALIDATION",1);
```

so:

1. Is this approach reasonable? any other thought maybe ?
2. What would be the best approach to change a file's single character ? Should I read it entirely,change and write back down ? or is there another way to do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not reasonable to have do something like this. A server that goes down regularly - that sounds like the problem you should be fixing. Is this an application configuration file? Can't you install a second copy of the application on your main server, using the alternate configuration?

Comment: the server is out of my control.

Answer (score 1):

Quite strange to have a server down for so long and so often :/

Anyway, easiest way to do this is to use `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` PHP [functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)